# How to write regular expression for CSRF token?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to write regular expression in `JMeter` regular expression extractor for a CSRFToken like:

> CSRFToken: `7e19ef44-5ff5-440b-865c-7ef56ccecc95`

The expression I am writing is like:

```
Ref. name: CSRFTokenValue
Regular expression - CSRFToken: (.*?);
Template: 1$1
Match no.: 1
Default value: ***CSRF Token Value not Fetched***
```

Now when I am using this expression for another request, CSRFtoken value is not getting extracted as it's showing default value -  `CSRF Token Value not Fetched` in result

Any idea how to write regular expression for such CSRFToken values ?

Answer (score 1):

Use greedy form

```
Regular expression - CSRFToken: (.*);
```

`.*?` non-greedy and in the above it would stop matching after matching the first empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If it retains it's uuid-ish nature, you can use this expression to grab it:

```
[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){3}-[a-f\d]{12}?
```

But Avinash's solution will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest amending your regular expression as follows:

1. Remove semicolon so the regex would look like: `CSRFToken: (.*)`
2. Amend "Template" to be `$1$`
3. Change your Regular Expression Extractor scope, by default it is searching in the response **Body**, if the CSRF token comes as a header you need to "tell" the Regular Expression Extractor to look in response headers.

If CSRF token comes as Cookie - you don't even need the Regular Expression Extractor, you can obtain the value from the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for detailed information on bypassing CSRF protection in your JMeter test script.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[:blank:]]{1}.*\z
```

In detail:

- `[[:blank:]]{1}` First space
- `*.` Any characters

Example of match:
https://regex101.com/r/eR9oY3/2

OR

```
[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+\Z
```

Example of match:
https://regex101.com/r/eR9oY3/3